# mysql duplicate key error during restoration through mysqldump data

Tags: primary-key, mysql

I have a mysql database which is having one table for geo location and saves latitude and longitude values of users. The fields are as followed

> TABLE `USER_LOCATION` (
>
> `LATITUDE` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
>
> `LONGITUDE` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
>
> `STATE` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
>
> `COUNTRY` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
>
> `ADDRESS` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
>
> `CITY` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
>
> `DISTRICT` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
>
> PRIMARY KEY (`LATITUDE`,`LONGITUDE`),
>
> KEY `latlong` (`LATITUDE`,`LONGITUDE`),
>
> KEY `longlat` (`LONGITUDE`,`LATITUDE`)
>
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Problem 1:- Some time fields get duplicate value and the insertion happens successfully.

Problem 2:- If I have taken mysqldump of data and try to restore with the same duplicate rows , then I receive duplicate PRIMARY KEY error like this.

**ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '17.4273-78.3316' for key 'PRIMARY'**

Now I am not able to understand that why the first problem happens and why this is detected in problem 2.